# Tabela dinâmica com dados vindo de uma input - js

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, funções

Oii gente, tudo bem?
Criei uma função que imprime os números primos, de acordo com o valor inserido pelo usuário no input.
Estou com uma dificuldade de acessar esse número para que a função funcione e retorne uma array e imrprir essa array numa tabela dinâmica. Estou iniciando ainda os estudo, alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda?

Segue o código:

```
<div class="card border-info container my-4 p-5 col-sm-4">
            <form class="text-center p-5" action="#!">
                <p class="h4 mb-4">Projeto - Números Primos</p>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" id="numerocalculo" class="form-control" name="numerocalculo" placeholder="Insira um número aqui" onblur="desafioPrimos(this);">
                        <input class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect btn-sm my-4 btn-block" type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="geradorTabela()">
                    </div>
</form>
        </div>

        <div class="card border-info mb-3 container p-5 text-center col-sm-4" id="divTabela"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* FUNÇÃO NÚMEROS PRIMOS */

                var numero = document.getElementById('numerocalculo').value;
                var primos = [];

            function desafioPrimos() {
                numero = parseInt(numero);
                numerosPrimos:
                    for (var x = 2; x <= numero; x++) {
                        for (var y = 2; y < x; y++) {
                            if (x % y === 0)
                            continue numerosPrimos;
                        };
                    primos.push(x);
                    };
                };                              


            /* FUNÇÃO GERADOR DE TABELA */
            function geradorTabela() {
                
                var primos = new Array();
                primos.push([desafioPrimos()]);


                var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
                table.border = "0";
                var columnCount = primos[0].length;

                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                    headerCell.innerHTML = primos[0][i];
                    row.appendChild(headerCell);
                }

                //Dados.
                for (var i = 1; i < primos.length; i++) {
                    row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        cell.innerHTML = primos[i][j];
                    }
                }

                var divTabela = document.getElementById("divTabela");
                divTabela.innerHTML = "";
                divTabela.appendChild(table);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu posso indicar qual o seu erro ao tentar acessar o valor do input.

Já adianto que existem outros problemas no código, e apenas essa correção não irá faze-lo funcionar, mas quanto a pergunta, eis a explicação.

No início do seu código, você está buscando o valor do input `numerocalculo` com a seguinte linha de código

```
var numero = document.getElementById('numerocalculo').value;
```

`value` é uma propriedade do tipo `string`, que é passado por valor, não por referência. Isso significa que se o valor do input for alterado, isso não irá refletir na sua variável `numero`, `numero` continuará representando o mesmo valor de quando ela foi inicializado, esse valor por sua vez é o que o seu input continha quando a página foi carregada: uma string vazia

Para pegar o valor numérico de `numerocalculo` no momento que a função `desafioPrimos` for executada, você deveria inicializar essa variável dentro da função:

```
function desafioPrimos() {
    var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('numerocalculo').value);
    var primos = [];

    // código para popular o array primos aqui

    return primos;
}
```

Também é possível que o valor do input não seja um valor numérico válido, então lembre de tratar essa possibilidade.

Comment: Obrigada, consegui que retornasse a array, inseri o parseInt dentro da função como sugeriu!